# Extract the last but one substring from a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have addresses in a column. I need to split just the last but one name from that column into another column.

The last but one substring is delimited by a space from both the right and left sides.

The content in cell A2 is "via Milano, 25 ROMA RM" and I entered the below formula in cell B2 (I need "ROMA" in cell B2)

I tried using the following formula:

```
=MID(A2,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",CHAR(1),LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""))))+1,LEN(A2))
```

But it returns the last substring from a given string (in this case "RM"). Can't manage to modify it to get the last but one substring. If useful: currently using macOS Catalina 10.15.7.

Edit: the string address is ALWAYS formatted in the same way "via", "street name","house number", "comune", "province".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like the hideous:

```
=LEFT(
RIGHT(
SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","!",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""))-1),
LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","!",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""))-1))-
SEARCH("!", SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","!",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""))-1))),

SEARCH(" ",
RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","!",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""))-1),
LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","!",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""))-1))-
SEARCH("!", SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","!",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""))-1)))))
```

though I am pretty sure there are faster/cleaner ways to get what you want. Note that "!" was just chosen as a character that wouldn't otherwise appear in the string. Also note this is why best practice is to store the smallest pieces of data as separate items rather than in one string!

REQUESTED EDIT: If you are just looking to get everything to the right of a comma and to the left of a space (e.g. "25" from "Via Milano, 25 ROMA RM") you can use something like the below

```
=LEFT(
TRIM(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-SEARCH(",",A2))),
SEARCH(" ", TRIM(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-SEARCH(",",A2)))))
```

Comment: Just edited the question. I applied US formatting to reach an 'international' audience while addresses are all in Italian formatting. Sorry if not specified before.

Comment: Got it, in that case you can just search for the comma instead of the space. I have edited my answer as well

Comment: It returns the "house number" instead of "comune"

Comment: Gah, missed that the house number was in there. Will edit again, give me a sec

Comment: Would you be so kind to post also the code to extract the substring after the comma, please?